# CanCan - users / tickets / employees

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, cancan

My associations as the following:

```
User has_many :employees

Employee belongs_to :user

Ticket has_many :employees
```

my routes is normal not nested for those models, 
How can I write the ability for assigned employees ?

Note user id is not the same as employee id

ability.rb

```
if user.has_role? :ticket_manager
      can :manage, Ticket, :employee_id => #how to match the employee.id
    end
```

Comment: Your requirement is not entirely clear. Can you elaborate, perhaps with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could do something like :

```
if user.has_role? :ticket_manager
  can :manage, Ticket do |ticket|
    ticket.employees.map(&:user_id).include?(user.id)
  end
end
```

However, as said in the doc https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks, note that this only works if an instance object is present. The block won't be evaluated when checking permissions for index for example.

Comment: user id is not the same as employee id  and i have added that to my question.

Comment: Yep I know. That's why I used the field user_id in employees. A user can manage tickets for its employees right ?